# What is the better way to make API with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rails-engines, rails-api

What is the better way to create API with Rails:

1. Create mountable rails [engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) in main application. In routes set url path for api: example.com/api/v1.
2. Create separately app with [rails-api gem](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) and make subdomain for api: api.example.com/v1.

Answer (score 1):

See this. This might be helpful.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning

http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning?view=asciicast